# ¡Buenas! greeting in morning

Tags: diferencias-regionales, género, saludos

[Another question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/450/bueno-as-hello-or-greeting) brings up the fact that in many countries, *¡Buenas!* is used as a greeting (as an abbreviation of *Buenas tardes* or *Buenas noches*). In regions where this is the case, what should be said in the morning (that is, when saying *Buenos días* is appropriate)? *Días* is masculine, not feminine, so does the greeting become *¡Buenos!*? Or is the feminine form used at all times during the day?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regardless of the time of the day, *¡Buenas!* is understood as an abbreviated greeting. Couldn't elaborate more on the exact meaning of why it is used like this, but we have become used to it as a very generic and informal way of greeting.

This is however a very informal greeting, so in any other situation *Buenos días*, *Buenas tardes* or *Buenas noches* should be used to avoid being considered disrespectful.

Comment: I wouldn't say *buenas* could ever be considered disrespectful. Only the most formal situations would **require** buenos días, etc

Comment: Not disrespectful in the way of an insult or anything of course, just not the kind of greet you would use in a professional environment, just to name an example.

Comment: It's clear that *buenas* is an informal greeting, but these days most of the world **is** informal. Maybe you wouldn't use it in court, with the military, or talking to a new corporate customer, but I'd say 95% of the time *buenas* is fine. (I do admit that living in Buenos Aires I might be biased. Perhaps this is not the case in more conservative countries/cities)

Comment: @Diego: The first time I heard it (in Bolivia) I thought the speaker was too lazy to finish the phrase.  But a day or two later, I realized it was the usual greeting.  With new people I tend to use the full phrase to avoid confusion.  (And, since it's clear I'm not a native speaker, I don't want to be seen as being lazy.)

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon not disrespectful but casual.

Answer (score 4):

"Buenas!" is a common (morning or anytime) greeting in Spain.

Comment: Also in Argentina. Rather informal.

Answer (score 4):

I live in Los Angeles, USA. My neighbours are mostly older latina/chicana women, they greet me with "buena" all of the time.

It's definitely a shortened, informal greeting that replaces 'buenas tardes' and 'buenas noches'. That being said, in the morning, they do (always) use 'Buenos Dias'. I usually respond with "buena" as well. It doesn't seem to be disrespectful but, that being said, they all know that I am not of latino/chicano origin, so they may be letting me slide. They do, however, appreciate that I try.

I try to use '¿cómo está usted? as they're older, but I do forget sometimes (cómo estás). They don't seem to care, again, it's possibly (likely) because I'm not a native speaker.

I do hear other neighbours (older and/or more friendly with them) just say "¿cómo?" but I don't ever do that (that's me just trying to show some respect/acknowledge that I'm not really good at Spanish/remind them that I'm not really that comfortable speaking Spanish).