# If asked, "¿Qué tiempo hace?" can you reply with just "Hace mal / buen"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, abreviaturas, tiempo-meteorológico

Someone over on Duolingo asked something similar to this two years ago.  I recently came upon it and have made an attempt to find an answer to this on the web, but have found nothing.  However, experience tells me that doesn't necessarily mean that it isn't used.  I've heard that in some parts of the Spanish-speaking world, some shortened forms of speech are in use such as [***¡Buenas!***](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/452/buenas-greeting-in-morning) for *¡Buenas tardes!* or *¡Buenas noches!* but I know that shortenings of any kind are kind of rare in Spanish and outside of *Yo también / Yo tampoco* and the occasional shortened word (e.g., *foto*), I have no idea if *Hace mal / buen* is used.  This seems like a good thing to search a movie script database for, but I have yet to find one that's free and easy to use, so I'm posting this question here to see if anyone can answer it.

---

**Si alguien pregunta, "¿Qué tiempo hace?" ¿se puede responder con sólo "Hace mal / buen"?**

Alguien en Duolingo preguntó algo similar a esto hace dos años.  Hace poco me encontré con ello y he intentado encontrar una respuesta en la web, pero no he encontrado nada.  Sin embargo, la experiencia me dice que eso no significa necesariamente que no se utilice.  He oído que en algunas partes del mundo hispanohablante se utilizan algunas formas abreviadas como [***¡Buenas!***](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/452/buenas-greeting-in-morning) para *¡Buenas tardes!* o *¡Buenas noches!* pero sé que los acortamientos de cualquier tipo son un poco raros en español y fuera de *Yo también / Yo tampoco* y la palabra acortada ocasional (p.ej., *foto*), no tengo ni idea de si se utiliza *Hace mal / buen*.  Esto parece una buena cosa para buscar en una base de datos de guiones de películas, pero todavía no he encontrado una que sea gratuita y fácil de usar, así que estoy publicando esta pregunta aquí para ver si alguien puede responderla.

*Por el amor del tiempo, traducción realizada, en parte, con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator)*

Comment: Si alguien me pregunta ¿qué tiempo hace? le respondería, ¿que tiempo hace que qué?. Lo usual el preguntar ¿Cómo está el clima? a lo que se responde «bueno», «malo» «llueve mucho» «ha hecho mucho frío» «está haciendo mucho calor» «normal», etc.

Comment: Why not just post in Spanish? Those translation programs do a disservice to everyone. My short answer here is no: hace bien o mal is not acceptable in Spanish. What is acceptable is: Buen tiempo or Mal tiempo.

Comment: @DGaleano Clima y tiempo no son la misma idea....

Comment: @Lambie En Colombia que no tenemos estaciones, si. Es más. «tiempo« se usa muy rara vez. Por eso digo... «si me preguntan...»

Comment: @Lambie En Colombia decimos «¿cómo **está** el clima?» para preguntar por el estado actual de las cosas. También decimos «¿cómo **es** el clima en ese pueblo?» para preguntar por la condición general de una región o lugar.

Comment: @DGaleano Pero hay temporadas de lluvia o de sol o de viento.  Eso no es clima, Es tiempo, a mi parecer. El clima es tropical; el tiempo es lluvioso.

Comment: El IDEAM (la meteorología oficial del gobierno colombiano) dice: **Prognóstico del tiempo** es su sitio: http://www.ideam.gov.co/

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker from Spain, the sentence "hace buen/mal" does not seem idiomatic to me.

The DLE marks [buen](https://dle.rae.es/buen) and [mal](https://dle.rae.es/mal?m=form) as *apócopes* (shortenings) of bueno and malo respectively but also stands that they are **used before a single masculine sustantive**. You have omitted such sustantive in your sentence.

I would use

> Hace bueno/malo

or

> Hace buen/mal tiempo

Comment: Your answer is a strong contender for the green check mark.  If it weren't for the fact that your answer seems restricted to Spain, I'd likely go ahead and give it to you now.  But, since it doesn't, I'd like to hold out for some other answers from the rest of the Spanish-speaking world.  If no one gives a more encompassing answer, I may just give it to you.  (And feel free to add more to your answer as well if you would like.)  In the meantime, I've given you an upvote.

Comment: @LisaBeck Ok, thank you. I've not gathered any additional related information so far. I don't know anything about its use in another Spanish-speaking countries.